# Ajax - Notice: Undefined index: id

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm learning all this php and script things, but I'm having problems with sending the information to the php. I hope you can help me. Thank you. This is the problem:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in ** on line 103

Php:

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['id']; //<< This is line 103
$sql = "SELECT id as ids,position FROM workerPosition WHERE '".$_POST['id']."'=id";
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
echo "Codigo:  <input type='text' name='ids' value='".$row['ids']."' disabled></br>";
echo "Nombre:  <input type='text' required='required' name='position'  placeholder='Max 50 caracteres' maxlength='50' value='".$row['position']."'>"; ?>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit-position").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id') 


        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:id},
        url: "editPosition.php",
        }).done(function( data ) {
            location.href = "editPosition.php"
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr id='". $row['id'] ."'>";
echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='buto' id='". $row['id'] ."'> <input type='submit' class='edit-position' id='". $row['id'] ."' value='Edit' /></td>";
echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: This is happening when the page redirects `location.href = "editPosition.php"` not on POST isn't it. If you're using the same page for get and post requests you should check which it is `if (isset($_POST))`

Comment: yes, i put it there because POST wasn't going to the page i want :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your ajax call is going to have the correct id in the POST variable, but when you do the `location.href` back to that `editPosition.php` file again, there's no POST variable, so that's when you're seeing that problem.

I'd use a success callback in your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {id:id},
    url: "editPosition.php",
    success: function(returnData) {
       console.log(returnData);
    }
});
```

**Edit:** I just saw your comment, if you want to programmatically go to the `editPosition.php` page with post data, you'll need to construct a hidden form that has `editPosition.php` as the action like so:

```
$('.edit-position').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var form = '<form method="post" action="editPosition.php"><input type="text" name="id" value="' + id + '" /></form>';
    $(form).submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But still not luck. When i click the button nothing happens now :(

Comment: @Maky-chan See my edit, you'll have to submit a programmatically created form.

Comment: @Maky-chan oops, I missed a `>` and forgot to include the `method="post"`, it should be correct now.

Comment: oh my, thank you so much. It did work <3
Tahnk you for your time ~